# Non-abelian variety of groups in which finite groups are abelian

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, universal-algebra

> Is there a non-abelian variety of groups $V$ such that any finite group from $V$ is abelian?

This was posed in a paper by Hanna Neumann (1967), but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: OP didn't react to the discussion. I edited by removing the first question because (1) it has an obvious answer (e.g., the  the free group on 2 generators) (2) even with additional hypotheses as suggested by several users (e.g., not torsion-free, or torsion) it has easy or standard examples (appearing at various places here at more focussed question) so a separate answer would not be very useful (3) asking 2 independent questions in the same post is usually not recommended (4) the second question is more interesting and has an accepted answer.

Comment: Trying to track the OP's reference, there are 2 references by Hanna Neumann in 1967 called *Varieties of groups*. The first is a whole 192-page book published at Springer (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-88599-0). The second is published at *Proc. Internat. Conf. Theory of Groups (Canberra, 1965) 251-259 Gordon and Breach, New York*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to Neumann's question is yes. A variety was constructed by Olshanskii , TY  - JOUR
AU  - Ol'shanskiĭ, A.,
Varieties in which all finite groups are abelian
DO  - 10.1070/SM1986v054n01ABEH002960
Mathematics of the USSR-Sbornik He also constructed nonabelian varieties where every periodic group is abelian. I think all these can be found in Olshanskii's book "Geometry of defining relations".